# Why does the area under a curve represent what it represents?

Tags: calculus, integration

I studied integration, differentiation .etc and i did study it pretty well. I know why the slope is important but i have yet not understood why we take the area under a curve.

For example, in a velocity-time graph, we take the derivative to find out the slope and that gives us acceleration. Makes sense bcos the amount of acceleration does indicate how steep the lines in the graph will be. But what does area have to do with the distance travelled.

Why is that by summing up infinitesimal rectangles under a curve giving u things like distance travelled, work done .etc??

Comment: At a particular time along the graph, you're going to increase your position by a really really (infinitesimal) small amount, but that increase is going to be proportional to the height of the graph at that point. When you add up all those really really small sections you're adding up the heights under the graph at every time. And, "all the heights", is kind of what area is.

Comment: I think the best word to describe integrals is "accumulation", as you move along the velocity graph you are "accumulating" displacement at the rate of the velocity. As you move along the graph you are also accumulating area at the rate of the height. Can you see how these two things are equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cover a distance $\Delta x$ in time $\Delta t$, then, by definition,
$$
\overline{v} = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}
$$
where $\overline{v}$ is your average velocity. Rearranging
$$
\Delta x = \overline{v} \Delta t
$$
If $\Delta t$ is small enough, then $\overline{v}$ is approximately equal to $v(t)$ where $t$ is the time on the clock at the start of the interval. Thus
$$
\Delta x \approx v(t) \Delta t
$$
On the left hand side is your change in position. The right hand side is a good approximation of the area under the graph of $v$ as a function of $t$ over the time interval $\Delta t$. If I add up all these small changes in position, I can find out how my position changed over all. The above approximation tells me that I can also do this by adding up approximations to the area of little slivers of the graph of $v$ as a function of $t$. Since adding up these little slices is the same thing as finding the area under the graph, my overall change in position will be equal to the area under the graph of $v$ as a function of $t$.

This is known as the fundamental theorem of calculus (depending on who you ask, it might be the second or first fundamental theorem of calculus). It's good that you've already studied some calculus, but if you aren't familiar with this sketch of the proof of the fundamental theorem, I would say that you still have a lot to learn.

Comment: I second your opinion